# Iterate over all vertices in a large Titan graph via Rexpro

Tags: titan, rexster

I am using Titan in my Python application (connecting via RexPro & [rexpro-python](https://github.com/bdeggleston/rexpro-python)).  I would like to perform a few operations that involve iterating over all vertices in the graph, and I'm wondering what would be the best way to do this (if there's even a sensible way at all).

The first idea that comes to mind is to request batches of `g.V` via the [i-j filter](http://gremlindocs.com/#filter/i-j), e.g.:

```
g.V[1..100]
g.V[101..200]
...
g.V[100001..100100]
...
```

However, the filter will load & iterate over vertices `0` to `i`, which will be prohibitively expensive for large graphs.

What's the best way to iterate over all vertices via RexPro?

Answer (score 1):

One fairly easy solution is to use a Rexster session variable with the `g.V` pipe, and request batches using [`Pipe.next`](http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/pipe-next)

```
res = conn.execute("my_iter = g.V; my_iter.next(100);", isolate=False)

while len(res) > 0:
    for d in res:
        yield d

    #get next 100
    res = conn.execute("my_iter.next(100);", isolate=False)
```

Comment: I think you've answered your own question here.  Keeping the iterator of V in the session is probably your best bet.